# Is it possible to force Meteor mobile app only access to server?

Tags: cordova, meteor

Is it possible to prevent direct browser access to the server? i.e. Only allow mobile app access.

The enforcement mechanism must not be easily hackable, e.g. if attacker sets `Meteor.isCordova = true` in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I put my routes in an `isCordova` block so they can only be accessed through the client.

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think anyone can just set `Meteor.isCordova=true;` in the console and gain access. I just tried it on my dev server and I couldn't access the routes even after setting that.

Example:

```
  Meteor.isCordova({
     FlowRouter.route('/blog/:postId', {
       action: function(params) {
           BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {area: "blog"});
       }
     });
  });
```

You can even set different 404 pages based on whether it's a mobile or web route. I have 3 public routes outside the `isCordova` block to allow email verification to succeed.